# Using a stack inside a Haskell Function

Tags: function, haskell, stack

I want to use a stack inside a Haskell function but I don't know how to use it. My function is supposed to work like this :

1. Take a string
2. Put some elements of this input string to output string and put others to stack.
3. Pop elements to that output string too.
4. Do 2 and 3 recursively until stack is empty.
5. Print the output string when stack is empty.

I don't know when and where to create that stack. I couldn't figure it out myself since I'm very new at Haskell programming. Since I haven't created any code I can't show any code either. Can you tell me what the function will look like in an algorithmic way? Where should I define the stack and output string? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One comfortable thing here is that standard Haskell list is a fine stack (natural, bearing in mind that stack is a more restricted kind of list). Your function might look something like this:

```
--takes one string and uses a stack to convert it to another string
doSomethingWithStack :: String -> [String] -> String
doSomethingWithStack str stack =
    let str' =   --here you embody your points 2 and 3
        stack' = --stack top is (head stack), push is (x : stack), pop is (tail stack)
        --... any change you'd want to make to any value turns into a new variable
    in case stack'' of --check the final variables
          [] -> str'' --if stack is empty, end
          _ -> doSomethingWithStack str'' stack'' --if not, repeat

--now, to make it pretty
fancyWrapper :: String -> String
fancyWrapper str = doSomethingWithStack str [] -- empty list is an empty stack

--because you should strive to separate pure and impure functions
--, I suggest that you do the print elsewhere, say
main = do
        str <- getLine
        print $ fancyWrapper str
```

Hopefully that is neither too little nor too much. Give it a try and ask more specific questions, once you run into problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The function is supposed to get only a string at first. Does this fit the structure you provide?

Comment: When you say "get a string", do you mean from the command line? If so, add `getLine` in a `do` block of `main`.

Comment: I mean function will be called like thisusing hugs:
function "stackoverflow"

Comment: Okay, but where does the stack come from then? Does it start empty?

Comment: yes, it starts empty, it has to be created somewhere inside the function, I don't know where.

Comment: Edited. Although now I'm not sure, if got it right? When repeating steps 2,3, does the old output string become the new input string? or should you keep reading from console?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. Actually the function  actually does infix to postfix conversion using Shunting yard algorithm. It just gets a string and converts it to postfix. It uses a stack to store operators and an output string to store the result. It only prints the final version of the output string when the stack becomes empty. But  it gets only a string and outputs only another string. In your definition you still give stack  as an input as far as I see, which is different if I understood right.